# Trying to hande http post request

Tags: node.js, post, same-origin-policy

I am trying to handle an HTTP post request to a nodejs server. 
This is the call:

```
$http({
url: 'my server url',
method: 'POST',
data: $scope.feedback,  
withCredentials: true
}).
```

This is where I am trying to handle it:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res){
console.log("Inside post method");
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer"); ...
```

When I try to post I cant even get the console message saying "Inside post method". I am posting from a different origin.

If anyone can help me understand why I am not hitting the code inside the POST handler I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you checked that you have the port open?  (e.g. `telnet host port`)

Answer (score 0):

> I am posting from a different origin.

You'll need to add the following to your post handler to allow cross-origin requests:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  // the rest of your code
```

Comment: I already have those, except for the wild card on the origin which is just set to the origin url